# How can I achieve unbuffering without Tcl?

Tags: shell, command-line, tcl, unbuffered, unbuffered-output

I'm a happy user of `unbuffer`, but am now faced with a system that doesn't have Tcl installed (and I don't have root privileges).

Can I achieve the same effect without using Tcl? A scripting solution would be nice, but I would not be averse to even writing some C...

Comment: `stdbuf` is written in C

Answer (score 2):

If you build Tcl and Expect from source you can configure them to install under a personal account without root access.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [man page of `stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), it seems the following might do it:

```
stdbuf --output=0
```

... followed by your command, *on the same command-line* (like you're used to with `unbuffer`).

You can also "unbuffer" your stdin and/or stderr if you like, with `--input=0` and `--error=0`.